# Create a new account by useradd command, can't login to the ssh server with new account?

Tags: digital-ocean

What happen is i created a new account with useradd command while in root account?
useradd an

then i reboot the cloud server. Try to login with new account an@'ssh-ip' instead of root@'ssh-ip'.

The following error appear.

could not chdir to home directory /home/an: No such file or directory

$ cd
-sh: 10: cd: can't cd to /home/an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `adduser` instead of `useradd` to create a new user, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/374870/home-directory-not-being-created) for details.